# Why Poisson and Normal laws of distribution are discrete and continuous respectively?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution, poisson-distribution

Many books say that , for example , Poisson law of distribution is discrete , but it does not tell why it is discrete. I know the difference between discrete and continuous random variables , but when teacher asks me a question as above , I could not answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the point in your question. Poisson distribution law describes the probability that a random variable takes the value $k$ for each $k$ from the set $0,1,2,3,\ldots$. (e.g. what is the probability that a customer service centre will get $k$ calls in a day). This is discrete. The number of calls is 3 or 4 or 5 etc and not $3.07, 4.22, 7.83712$ etc. (The average number over a period could be a fractional value, however).